# Translate pseudocode to x86 assembly

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, pseudocode

I need to translate the next pseudo-code to assembly. only need to read 5 numbers in array and compare with the last value. Params are taken well.

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
tmp= not L0

tmp = not ( not tmp and not L1)

tmp= tmp or L2

tmp = not (not tmp or not L3)

tmp= tmp and L4

if(tmp == L5 )
    valido
sino 
    invalido
```

and its my "solution"  :

```
EsLicenciaValida PROC licencia: dword


    mov ebx, licencia 
    mov edx,[ebx] 

    mov ecx, edx
    neg ecx

    add ebx, 4
    mov edx,[ebx]
    not edx
    not ecx
    and ecx, edx
    not ecx

    add ebx, 4
    mov edx,[ebx]
    or ecx, edx

    add ebx, 4
    mov edx,[ebx]
    not edx
    not ecx
    or ecx,edx
    not ecx 

    add ebx, 4
    mov edx,[ebx]
    and ecx, edx

    add ebx, 4
    mov edx,[ebx]
    cmp edx, ecx
    jne invalido

    valido: 
        mov eax, ecx
        jmp salir
    invalido:
        mov eax, 0000h

    salir:


    ret
EsLicenciaValida ENDP
```

`ECX` register have the tmp value of the pseudo-code. `EBX` the value in actual position of array.

Some one knows whats wrong? Thanks for all =)

Comment: What is your question? Is your code not doing what you expect? If not, how does it differ?

Comment: oh, im sorry. In cmp value, refuse values thay shoud accept. For example if you insert an array with values in hexadecimal: A-A-A-A-A-32 (50) the sum of all other shuld be 50, but dont works, go the invalid value.

Comment: `neg ecx` is the error. The result for five '0Ah' (0x0A) is 10d. This looks like a puzzle. You should find the five numbers that sum up to 50 **and** "algorithm" to 32h. I didn't test if this is solveable.

Answer (score 0):

> an array with values in hexadecimal: A-A-A-A-A-32

Why do you expect a **sum** is calculated?
Why do you expect the result to be 50?

The number in L5 is 10! (derived from the presented pseudocode)

Comment: Man if you start in 0 possition, [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]  - L5 then its OK

Comment: original problem calculate the sum (on C++) now we must sustitute the  function in C by the function in assembly, with this pseudocode algorithm.